# Why I can't bind the Command to the button?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, command

I work on a project target on Windows Phone 7.5 and above.

**What I have**
ListBox

```
<ListBox    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding singleFavListItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource userFavBoardListItemTemplate}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding userfavboardlist}" 
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="12,0,0,12"/>
```

ItemTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="userFavBoardListItemTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            Text="{Binding boardName}" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" 
            Foreground="{StaticResource TitleColor}"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding quitBoardCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding boardUrl}"
                Content="Quit" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Grid.Column="1"
        FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" 
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource DateArticalCategoryColor}" 
        Foreground="{StaticResource DateArticalCategoryColor}">
     </Button>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

ViewModel

```
public MyFavListViewModel()
{
    this._quitBoardCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.quitBoardAction);
}
private ICommand _quitBoardCommand;
public ICommand quitBoardCommand
{
    get
    {
        return this._quitBoardCommand;
    }
}
private void quitBoardAction(object p)
{
    //my business logic here
}
```

Error
I found a error in the OutPut windows:

> 'xicihutong.Model.UserFavBoardListRawData' (HashCode=55845053).
>   BindingExpression: Path='quitBoardCommand'
>   DataItem='xicihutong.Model.UserFavBoardListRawData'
>   (HashCode=55845053); target element is
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Button' (Name=''); target property is
>   'Command' (type 'System.Windows.Input.ICommand')..

**What's the problem**
What confuse me is that the quitBoardCommand never get triggered when I tap the button? It seems that I can't bind the Command to the button, the DelegateCommand part is right, because I can use it to bind command in other pages. And the SelectedItem of the ListBox works right, also.

Why I can't bind this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the `DataContext` of your `ListBox` to bind to your command. To fix this, give your `ListBox` a name then reference the command property

```xml
<ListBox x:Name="myLB"
    <!-- rest of your stuff -->
/>

<Button 
    Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.quitBoardCommand, ElementName=myLB}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding boardUrl}"
    Content="Quit" />
```

Comment: Message: "Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." -_-, am i miss something....

Comment: Are you sure the error comes when you type the above code? PresentationFramework assembly contain all base controls used in WP. Check that the file is there: \Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\PresentationFramework.dll

Comment: unfortunately, there is no "v4.0" folder, there is only "v3.5" and "v3.0" below " \Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\" :( And only in "v3.0" folder gets a "PresentationFramework.dll", and I can't refer it

Comment: Did you upgrade your project to Windows Phone 8?

Comment: Try re-installing Windows Phone 8 SDK, it should install all v4.0 files for you.

Comment: it's a project based on Windows Phone OS 7.1, @_@ not Windows Phone 8, so does it mean that I can't do this type of binding in mango using this grammar?

Comment: No it works on both WP7.1 and WP8. The error you are getting has nothing to do with the binding.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code. You don't forget to change "datacontext" name.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="userFavBoardListItemTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            Text="{Binding boardName}" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" 
            Foreground="{StaticResource TitleColor}"/>
        <Button Command="{Path=quitBoardCommand,Source={StaticResource datacontext}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding boardUrl}"
                Content="Quit" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Grid.Column="1"
        FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" 
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource DateArticalCategoryColor}" 
        Foreground="{StaticResource DateArticalCategoryColor}">
     </Button>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: What is the DataContext here? I change it to <Button Command="Path=quitBoardCommand,Source={StaticResource DataContext}", it passes the code check, but fails in the runtime.

Comment: datacontext is your viewmodel resource key

<UserControl 
xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:your.namespace.MyFavListViewModel">
<UserControl.Resources>
        <viewmodel:MyFavListViewModel x:Key="datacontext" />
</UserControl.Resources>

Comment: {MS.Internal.WrappedException: Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.

Comment: with your help, i finally know the problem is the datacontext inside a itemtemplate is not where the ICommand actually is. The real problem here should be how to refer a DataContext within a ItemTemplate -_-

Comment: @AlbertGao that depends on you, you could pass it down to your view model. Or you could use RelativeSource to find a view element that has your desired DataContext.